bash loop with jq
How can I update a json file using jq in a loop as below ? json file need to have the .queryToken updated and .result array appended using json in curl response body
while true
do
  curl -k --location 'https://api.../queryMore' \
          --user "uname:pswd" \
          --data "$(jq '.queryToken' Process.json)" |
   jq '{
         numberOfResults: .numberOfResults,
         queryToken: .queryToken,
         result: .result
       }'
 #update .queryToken in Process.json and append .result to .result in Process.json
 #break if no .queryToken
done

The file and curl response are identical in structure as in example below
{
    "@type": "QueryResult",
    "queryToken": "<base64text>",
    "result": [
      ...
    ]
}


What's the type of .result? A string, an array, and object? Have you considered using a proper programming languages like perl/ruby/python instead of a shell?

.result is an array of objects. If not jq/bash then fallback is nodejs script

An example of what you have and of what you want, please

The use case is for the api call as per https://help.boomi.com/docs/atomsphere/integration/atomsphere%20api/r-atm-query_paging_f5c7070d-9743-431b-8bf5-305bf314d307/

Make it easy for us to help you. Put the example of what you have and what you want into your question please

{
"@type": "QueryResult",
"queryToken": "/nd0PlROcmuUK8MV8KPzCVXwA/pgZZ0NfsYjhqLNyothPzrFIh0OQLP6Hq3ERMSAl38Dz3NV5otJ/0+aCDDsTypO0QdfW8E1g6HO418j",
"result": [
...
]
}

Sorry.. I am using my mobile to update now, but will elaborate when near a better device

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

break if no .queryToken is easy enough - extract the value of .queryToken and break the loop if it's an empty string. I don't understand what you want by the other requirement. An example would help tremendously

Could be something like:
set -o pipefail
while
  token=$(jq -e .queryToken Process.json) &&

    curl --insecure \
         --fail \
         --no-progress-meter \
         --location \
         --user "uname:pswd" \
         --data "$token" \
         'https://api.../queryMore' |
      jq -c --slurpfile old Process.json '
        . as $new |
        $old | first |
        .numberOfResults += ($new.numberOfResults) |
        .result += ($new.result) |
        .queryToken = ($new.queryToken)' > Process.json.new &&

    mv Process.json.new Process.json
do
  continue
done

(also replacing your -k with its long form --insecure so as not to loose sight of the fact that it is insecure. Also adding --fail for curl to report errors by the HTTP server; I've also moved the URL to the end. Having it after --location was misleading, as it's not an argument to that option; --location is a flag to tell curl to follow redirects¹; you should also consider using safer ways to pass the credentials as passing them on the command line is insecure).

¹ as supplied by the HTTP server in the Location HTTP header. See also the --location-trusted for the --user credentials to also be sent to the target of the redirection (potentially dangerous especially when combined with -k aka --insecure).

I am still not sure what clarity is required. Anyhow thanks to Stéphane Chazelas for the solution, i can confirm that it works as desired.
